# How does torque frequency affect a wing's movement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, simulations, drag, lift

**Preface**

I'm playing with a python based simulation in which I solve the ODE $I\ddot\phi=\tau_{motor}-\tau_{drag}$. This ODE represents Newton's 2nd law (in terms of torques) of a wing that is attached to a rotating motor. $\tau_{motor}$ is for me to choose, and $\tau_{drag}\propto C_D(\alpha)\cdot(\dot\phi)^2$ where $C_D(\alpha)$ is a drag coefficient that depends on the angle of attack $\alpha$. As of now, I use a simplified version of $\alpha$ (the angle of attack) which is $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}{\rm sign}(\dot\phi)$. This simply says that $\alpha$ is either $45\deg$ if the wing moves forwards or $-45\deg$ if the wing moves backward.

**Experiment**

I choose multiple frequencies $f\in[1,2,5,10,20,30]$ and solve the ODE given $\tau_{motor}=cos(2\pi ft)$. For either one of those, I also measure the lift force induced in the motion, which is $F_{lift}\propto C_L(\alpha)\cdot(\dot\phi)^2$.

**My Expectation**

It is expected that when $f$ is higher, the average lift force would also be higher. This is clear when $f=0$ as the wing stays still and no lift force is generated.

**Results**

It turns out that the average lift force stays relatively the same, but the amplitude of $\phi$ decreases when $f$ increases, As the following plot shows:

[image: Plot]

You can see that if $f=5$ the amplitude of $\phi$ is $[-2.5,2.5]$ radians but if $f=20$ it is $[-1,1]$ radians. When taking the mean value of the force plots, the results are pretty much the same.

**Question**

Why is that so? Is my intuition wrong or am I just missing something?

Comment: I see many mistakes here, so that your model doesn't represent the physical system. I'd suggest to (re)start from scratch, from a model-based mathematical system of the wing (even a 2D airfoil should be ok) and limit the investigation to small angles of incidence, otherwise, you need to model dynamic stall. Even the expression of the angle of incidence $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4} sign(\dot{\phi})$ has no physical meaning (where does the $sign$ come from?) and wrong physical dimensions (angle  = angular velocity?)

Comment: Thanks, @basics. Is this not the equation of motion on the wing? (at least, a very simplified one). Furthermore, can you elaborate on the question of "where does the sign come from?"

Comment: It has no reason to be there. This evening I'll leave you a model that you can use. Are you using Colab or other methods to collaborate on Python scripts? If you're looking for a rigid wing, it should be quite easy to derive the governing equations

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm working with Colab. Having said that, my lab has previously provided me a proper simulation. This whole task of mine is to take only the most basic dynamic I can think of and see how can one choose the motor's torque to optimize lift.

Comment: Minor edit: Use `{\rm sign}` instead of `sign` in math formatting. It looks like a function ${\rm sign}()$, instead of the variables $s\,i\,g\,n()$